# The type ReadOnlyMemory<> and ReadOnlySequence<> is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have a C# Desktop application I am developing which is meant to read text from a file and convert it into a `JsonDocument`. I have installed and referenced the `System.Text.Json` library developed by Microsoft in order to read from the JSON file.
I am however getting a strange error that requires me to reference classes from the `System.Memory` namespace, and a particular version to be exact. I am unsure of how to add these references to my project because when I use NuGet Package manager to install `System.Memory` I am getting conflicts with my current packages.
Project is targetting .NET framework 4.6

How can I go about solving these errors without affecting my other packages?

[image: error_screenshot]

Comment: "because when I use NuGet Package manager to install System.Memory I am getting conflicts with my current packages" - what errors *specifically*? We can't help without that. This *sounds* like a binding redirects problem - see https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/

Comment: how do I determine the oldVersion in the binding redirects? @MarcGravell

Comment: I believe the blog post I linked to covers that